# Cauchy Sequence Convergence Prove or Give Counterexample

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Prove or give a counterexample: if a sequence of real numbers $\{x_n\}$ from
$n=1$ to $\infty$
has the property that for all $\epsilon >0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb N$
such that for all $n \ge N$ we have $|x_{n+1} - x_n| < \epsilon$, then $\{x_n\}$ is a convergent sequence. How is this different from the definition of a Cauchy
sequence?

Attempt: For the second part of the problem, I know that it's different from the definition of a Cauchy sequence as it's taking the next part of the sequence and subtracting it from the current part of the sequence.

For the first part, I'm not sure how to go about doing this; originally, I thought I could do something such as $|x_{n+1} - x_n| < \epsilon/2$, in then use the triangle inequality. But I'm not sure we can do that. Thoughts and comments?

And apologies ahead of time for the lack of formatting.

Comment: Your condition is false. The qualifiers for Cauchy Convergence are very precise; to wit, the statement is that for any $\epsilon > 0$ I can find $N$ such that for any $n,m > N$ we have $|x_n - x_m| < \epsilon$. To see a concrete example, try $x_n = \sum_{i  = 1}^n i^{-1}$.

Comment: Your idea with the triangle inequality will not work, as once $n$ is chosen, Cauchyness allows me to choose $m$ to be absurdly large, in which case I cannot get a good bound using only that $|x_n - x_{n+1}| <\epsilon$.

Comment: It might be worth noting that if $|x_{n+1}-x_n|<r^n$ for some $r<1$, the sequence *is* Cauchy.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Try the sequence of harmonic numbers $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i}$ and see if it converges.

Comment: Or (perhaps easier) $x_n = \sqrt{n}$.

Comment: @GEdgar That sequence does not have the required property.

Comment: @FrankMcGovern Yes, it does. For each $n\in \Bbb N$, $$\sqrt {n+1}-\sqrt {n}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt \psi}$$ for some real $\psi\in[n,n+1]$.

Comment: @Peter Oh, of course. I don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: I tried the harmonic numbers for 1/i, and it does converge (to 0). Even if I were to use the example for my given question, (xn+1 − xn), the sequence would still converge, as it's still constrained by L+epsilon, L-epsilon.

Maybe I'm not understanding this 100%. Could you elaborate some more, primarily on the example? I want to understand the example before we continue.

Comment: @noname: It's well known that as $n \to \infty$, $H_n = \sum \frac{1}{i} \to \infty$. Thus the sequence of $H_n$ does not converge. But the difference between $H_n$ and $H_{n+1}$ goes to $0$, and thus satisfies your condition.

Comment: Doh. I don't know why I didn't see that as a summation sign. Time to take a break. That was my fault. 

Are there any other common examples? Some of the ones we've used in class are 1/n, 1-1/n, etc. Would I want to take a look at something that is diverging, but when I look at the difference, it'll result in something that approach es a limit?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the hint on harmonic series. I was trying to work backwards to get something that would result in 1/n; the harmonic series is what came up. Took a while to work it out, and I had help with a few members of my class.

Answer (score 2):

Note that, a sequence ${x_n}$ is Cauchy if

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} |x_{n+p}-x_n| = 0 \quad \forall p\geq 1. $$

Now, as an example of your case, try $x_n=\ln(n)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

In general, every Cauchy sequence is $\mathbb{R}$ is convergent. (Three Steps)

1. Prove that every Cauchy sequence is bounded.
2. Use the *Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem* to conclude that it must have a convergent subsequence.
3. Show that a Cauchy sequence having a convergent subsequence must itself be convergent.

(The *Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem* states that every bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ has a convergent subsequence.)

Note that the sequence given in your question is a special case of a Cauchy sequence.

---

To clarify the other assumptions:

**(1) Harmonic series is NOT Cauchy.**

Recall defintion: $\forall \varepsilon >0, \exists N \in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall m,n>N,|a_n-a_m|<\varepsilon $

Choose $m=2N$ and $n=N$. Then $$\left | \sum_{i=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{i}  - \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i}  \right |=\sum_{i=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{i}  - \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i} = \sum_{i=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{i} = \frac{1}{n+1} +\frac{1}{n+2} + ... + \frac{1}{2n} < \frac{1}{n} +\frac{1}{n} + ... + \frac{1}{n} = n \left (\frac{1}{n}  \right )=1 (=\varepsilon  ) $$

But, remember that $\varepsilon >0$ is chose arbitrarily. So the harmonic series is not Cauchy.

**(2) If $a_n$ is Cauchy, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} (x_{n+1}-x_n) = 0$. The converse is NOT true.**

Counterexample for the converse:

Take $a_n=\sqrt{n}$.

$\lim_{n \to \infty} (\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}) = 0$, but $(\sqrt{n})_{n\in\mathbb{n}}$ is not Cauchy.